# VB Await an asyc call that also awaits a call

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to VB and not very familiar with async functions.
I need to fix a bug in existing code where some code is building a report before the data has finished loading.

The problem is that BuildReport() is getting called before the loadOption1(data) has been called. I need the application to wait for all of LoadAsync() to complete before running, but when it waits for GetData(), the application is returning to start() and running BuildReport() too early.

The code looks roughly like this:

```
Public Async Sub start()

    await LoadAsync()

    BuildReport() ' this must not run until everything in Load is complete

End Sub

Public Async Function LoadAsync() As System.Threading.Tasks.Task        
'this is called from other locations, not just from Start()

    dim data = await GetData() 'call to database
    ' at this point start() continues to run
    ' but we need it to keep waiting for these next calls to complete

    'these calls are synchronous, builds objects needed for the report 
    loadOption1(data)
    loadOption2(data)
    loadOption3(data)

    'now we want to return to start()
End Function


Public Async Function GetData(s As Scenario) As Task(Of DataResults)

    ...

    Dim resp = Await Task.Run(Function() ConfigWebService.FetchIncentives(req)) ' soap call

End Function
```

(each function is in separate classes within the same project)

I have tried removing the await from the start function; the options load after BuildReport() is called.

if I remove the await from the GetData() call, passing data.result to the loadoptions functions, the whole application just hangs forever.

I'm stumped. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

**edit: updated the sample to correctly reflect the actual code**

Update:
I have tried everything I can think of, from .ContinueWith(False), to attaching to the parent task, to using .ContinueWith(), but nothing has worked so far.
As soon as the code hits the await inside the LoadAsync(), the task in Start() is considered complete

Comment: Is the bug related to the Async / Await?  What are you trying to fix?

Comment: The problem with passing `data.Result` is probably that you're doing this from the UI thread, and blocking on the result of a `Task` is well-known to deadlock when you try this.

Comment: The version with both `Await`s included generally looks correct.  `BuildReport` shouldn't run until `Load` is finished.  The only potential issue I can see is that the type of `Load` isn't correct, as declared the type is `Object` but it should be `Task`.

Comment: Is that `Load()` function in the same class as `start()` is?  Also, are there any async calls triggered from within the `GetData()` function? Lastly, side note... best practice is to suffix your async method names with the word Async.  `LoadAsync()`, and `GetDataAsync()`.

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo, but your `Start` function needs to be declared as `Async` as well if you want to use `Await`

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. Please ignore the rough syntax and signature issues, that's just due to my simplifying for posting. I'll update the code sample. The Start() and LoadAsync() functions ARE in different classes. I will try looking into using data.Result on a different thread and see if that helps any.

Comment: Try adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to your call to `GetData()`.  Like:  `Dim data = await GetData().ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: @DBro Just tried, and the issue still occurs :(

Comment: Re "using data.Result on a different thread," be careful, you can still end up on the UI thread when you don't necessarily expect it.  I'd recommend reading most of Stephen Cleary's work on `Async` and `Await`.  A good entry point is this article: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html (I'd also recommend the MSDN article he wrote that is linked at the end.)

Comment: @Craig Yes, there is an await on FetchIncentives. Sample updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that seemed to work was to making a isLoading flag that gets set to true at the start of LoadAsync(), then set to false after the LoadOptions3() finished. Then checking if the flag's value has changed in a loop with a delay

```
Public Async Sub start()

    await LoadAsync()

    For i As Integer = 1 To 50
        If Not IsLoading Then Exit For
        Await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100)
    Next

    BuildReport() 

End Sub
```